# How can I filter hunks using regex from interactive add/checkout?

Tags: regex, git, interactive

I have changes in the last commit I want to partially discard using an interactive mode. So I'm using:

```
git checkout -p HEAD~1
```

But the thing is that there is too much changes I have to go through and I need something to filter them out, preferably regex, so that only hunks matching my regex are shown in the interactive checkout.

Btw it would be awesome if the solution could be also used for interactive add:

```
git add -p
```

I know about `--word-diff-regex`, but that is applicable only to `git diff` :(

Comment: `git add -p` is a Perl script, in `$(git --exec-path)git-add--interactive`. This is use for `git checkout -p` as well (`git checkout` runs it with `--patch=checkout`). Since it *is* a Perl script, you can copy it to your own command, and modify its "select hunk" routine to apply a regular expression first.